# Mostrar PDF en una pestaña nueva del navegador

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Buen dia tengo un problema, tengo un documento pdf alojado en una base de datos de tipo varbinary, al abrirlo se descarga automaticamente. Lo que quiero es que se abra en una pestaña del navegador y asi si al usuario le interesa lo pueda descargar.

este es mi codigo

```
            byte[] miArray = ((byte[])miTabla.Rows[0]["documento"]);
            this.Context.Response.ContentType = "\".pdf\",\"application/pdf\"";
            this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=documento.pdf");
            this.Context.Response.BinaryWrite(miArray);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

la variable miArray contiene el documento extraido de la base de datos.
Nuevamente lo que quiero es que se abra y no que se me descargue automaticamente.

Gracias por su atencion.

Answer (score 1):

Cambia `content-disposition` por `inline` en vez de `attachment`.

```
this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=documento.pdf");
```

En [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395151/content-dispositionwhat-are-the-differences-between-inline-and-attachment) hay más información.

Answer (score 0):

utiliza window.open

```js
window.open('rutadonde lo guardaras/nombre del archivo.pdf','_blank');
```

claro esto en js

Comment: y como aplica esto a el còdigo que ya tiene avanzado?